# Update query performance improvement (MS-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, nonclustered-index, parallelism

```
UPDATE M SET ARCHIVE_FLAG = 'N' FROM MARKPOSTED_TMP M WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SHFMKPSTMM S INNER JOIN SHIFT_TMP S1 
ON M.MARKID = S.MARKID AND 
S.SHIFTID = S1.SHIFTID AND S1.ARCHIVE_FLAG <> 'Y')
```

The above query is currently updating around 414163 rows in 44 seconds, And I want to improve its performance by maybe doing it parallel or updating in batch?

I have tried with the below query-

```
UPDATE M SET ARCHIVE_FLAG = 'N' FROM MARKPOSTED_TMP M WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SHFMKPSTMM S INNER JOIN SHIFT_TMP S1 
ON M.MARKID = S.MARKID AND 
S.SHIFTID = S1.SHIFTID AND S1.ARCHIVE_FLAG <> 'Y') OPTION (MAXDOP 8);
```

But only with 4-6 seconds better result

Execution plan suggests index scan non-clustered on SHFMKPSTMM  table is taking 49% cost. But I can't remove the index from that table.

Any help in the better query formulation to improve the performance?

Comment: Could you please upload the actual execution plan on brentozar.com/pastetheplan and what is the expectation of duration for updating 400k rows update.

Comment: Due to data confidentiality, I can't share the execution plan.

Comment: And for the timings, The faster the better. I have read some articles and they state that running in batches reduces the time, But somehow am not able to divide my query into batches, any help for performance improvement would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: If the _execution plan_ and _database schea_ are really [trade secrets](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/), your best option is to hire a consultant and write up an NDA.

Comment: Maybe adding `WHERE M.ARCHIVE_FLAG != 'N'` could speed up the query a little.

Comment: @LuvGupta You can use [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/sql-performance/anonymize-your-plans) to locally anonymize your **actual execution plan** and then you can upload the anonymous plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/PasteThePlan). It'll be the best way anyone can help you with performance improvements, otherwise there's not much else that can be suggested that hasn't been said yet.

Comment: Btw what indexes do you currently have on `MARKPOSTED_TMP`, `SHFMKPSTMM`, and `SHIFT_TMP`? (Please provide the full index definitions in an update to your post.)